# When we look for equilibrium, do we set sum of portfolios equa to zero or equal to outstanding shares?

Tags: financial-markets

Let us say we have a market with $K$ agents who choose their portfolios $(\theta_k^i)$ of how many shares of each asset $i$

In equilibrium, my question is whether the condition is to say $\sum_k \theta_k^i$ = 0 or to say that $\sum_k \theta_k^i = \text{supply}^i$, where the right-hand side equals shares outstanding of asset $i$.

I've seen models with both these equilibrium conditions used, and am wondering what the difference is, intuitively. In particular, I do not understand the second one: how can we have "shares outstanding" be an independent, exogeneous notion to our agents? Don't our agents themselves supply shares through their choice of portfolios?

Comment: It depends whether you want to model investors separately (and assume outstanding shares are exogenous) like most Finance books do, or whether you want to model the whole economy including the issuance of shares by entrepreneurs/companies (like Arrow & Debreu do).

Comment: Indeed Alex C is right. Just something that might help: often research papers will mention the theta equal to zero as being zero net supply and the theta = supply as positive net supply. 

Most likely stuff such as debt is in zero net supply in most models.